Unable to register and process callback
Good day, I am writing in python 3.11 using aiogram 3.13.1. I encountered a problem with recorders
dp.callback_query.register(callback)
dp.callback_query.register(add_money, Main.add, F.data == "add")

I've searched the internet but still can't figure out how to register a callback with a condition on callback_data or state
It doesn't give any error code, but only the first callback is registered, it just ignores the second one
Here is the whole code:


from config import get_data, cmd

import logging

from msg_handler import *

from call_handler import *

from func import *



logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

dp = get_data("dp")



# Message Register

dp.message.register(start, cmd("cmd", cmd="start"))

dp.message.register(add_nick, cmd("state", state="add"))

dp.message.register(amounted, cmd("state", state="amount"))



# Callback Register

dp.callback_query.register(callback)

dp.callback_query.register(add_money, Main.add,  F.data == "add_money")

#dp.callback_query.register(add_money, cmd("state", state="add"))



if __name__ == "__main__":

    asyncio.run(main(dp, get_data("bot")))


Разобрался сам...
